# Why add "__NSSingleXXXI" private class in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, ios10

There are three new private class added is iOS 10

- __NSSingleObjectArrayI
- __NSSingleObjectSetI
- __NSSingleEntryDictionaryI

When container init with single object, the cluster of container will use these three new class.

In iOS 9, '__NSArray0' and '__NSDictionary0' added too.

I don't know the reason to add these special private class. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Private classes are the classes that are for apple's internal use only, User/we cant use it(unless you tweak or jailbreak iphone). So, now adding new private classes or removing them is based on their internal need, only the programmer from apple can only tell why they added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just an optimisation most likely. For example, `__NSSingleObjectSetI` doesn't need to bother with an actual hash table, because there's only one object to worry about. Methods like `containsObject:` don't need to loop over anything or look anything up, it can simply compare the argument with the single object that the set/array/dictionary represents.

Similarly, `__NSArray0` (assuming it is used for empty arrays) can have methods like `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` simply send `copy` to the argument and return it. A minor optimisation, but an optimisation nonetheless.

You shouldn't use these classes directly of course (since they are private, and an implementation detail), the framework will use these classes automatically. Since it *is* an implementation detail, I can't be certain of the true purposes of these private classes, I'm only guessing.